# Orphaned blocks on September 13, 2014

Tags: blockchain.info, stale-block

I'm new in the Bitcoin World. Today I did my second transaction for just 0.005 BTC but 2 hours after, it's unconfirmed yet. The transaction is in the block 320385 and it is orphaned. I saw the statistics for orphaned block in blockchain.info and today are 10 orphaned blocks and this is a high value according the graphic.

My cuestion is:

1.- How much time will my transaction to be included in other block?.

2.- What happened on september 13, 2014?, Why are there 10 orphaned blocks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Today I did my second transaction for just 0.005 BTC but 2 hours after, it's unconfirmed yet. The transaction is in the block 320385 and it is orphaned.

Is it in a block, or is it unconfirmed?

> block 320385

Which block 320385? [This one](https://blockchain.info/block-index/463427/00000000000000001af016dd744624803372985edda587f0bf5d9689118cdae8) or [this one](https://blockchain.info/block-index/463426/00000000000000000c06e54c51c91aa306f1d043c05ef36afff446041243babb)?

> today are 10 orphaned blocks and this is a high value according the graphic.

Huh, that's pretty odd. Screenshot for posterity:

[image: Blockchain mistakenly thinks that blocks are orphaned]

It's unusual for blockchain.info to be wrong, but it definitely is in this case. This is the best chain that my client can find:

```
2014-09-13 01:59:04.460 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000652d48e212a9fdb16ce57d7097b76200a2fe5e9cd643fe  height=320406  log2_work=80.639033  tx=46574398  date=2014-09-13 01:56:16 progress=0.999993
```

The chain that blockchain.info thinks is invalid appears valid to my client. They'll probably have it sorted out in a few hours.

Comment: Can exists two blocks with the same number? I think no, both links point to the same block: 320385 (orphaned block)

Comment: 3 hours and 30 mins and the tx is unconfirmed yet.

Comment: Now the orphaned blocks rise up to 27. Is this normal?

Comment: `Can exists two blocks with the same number` Yes.

Comment: Correction: 'It's NOT unusual for blockchain.info to be wrong'. It's been horrible for months at least.

Comment: @Jannes If you can provide a specific example, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @NickODell There was a lot of ruckus in Reddit's /r/Bitcoin about Blockchain.info having issues with an API vulnerability. The issue was with parsing and address balance misrepresentation. I don't understand the technicality but I do know they went offline to fix it so it's possible

Comment: Don't use blockchain.info that much but I've seen people complain about inconsistencies on reddit a lot. At one point it was a corruption in their database indexes and they any offline to fix that. But as far as I can tell they never really recovered. If you see something weird on blockchain.info always double check with one of the many others. Blocktrail, blockr... Whatever they're called.